# Iterate in ranges in Python

Tags: loops, for-loop, iteration, range

in Python, I need to iterate numbers in ranges like this:

```
0-200
201-400
401-800
801-1200 
etc.
```

until the len() of a certain file is reached.

i.e. the first steps includes 200 elements and the further ones 199. But it would be no problem, if all of them would include 200, meaning:

```
0-200
201-401
402-602
603-803
```

The most important thing is to receive all documents behind these numbers in this ranges of approximately 200 once.

When I tried it, I was not happy with the result:

```
a = 0
b = 200

for i in range(a, len(files), b):
    print(a,b)
    print('\n')
    a = a+b
    b = b+b
```

because I get this output containing duplicates ("200" is in the first and second range) and missing ranges (e.g. 400-600):

```
0 200
200 400
600 800
1400 1600
etc.
```

or this example:

```
a = 0
b = 200

for i in range(a, len(files), b):
    print(a,b)
    print('\n')
    a = a+b+1
    b = b+b
```

also unsatisfying result:

```
0 200
201 400
602 800
1403 1600
etc.
```

There are also some unwanted jumps and for example a missing range between 400 and 600.

Does anyone have an idea how to handle this? As I said, it does not really matter, which exact range is underlying. I just need a constant one covering all numbers once.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Ok, I got a solution for the first problem concerning the jumps with "a=a+200" and "b=b+200" in the end of the code. Still, there are duplicates. Because now the output is: 0-200; 200-400; 400-800

Answer (score 0):

Ok I seem to have a solution:

```
a = 0
b = 200

for i in range(a, len(files), b):
    print('\n')
    print(a, b)
    a = a + 200 +1
    b = b + 200 +1
```

delivers the output:

```
0 200    

201 401    

402 602    

603 803    

804 1004
```

Still thank you, if you've tried anything. I would keep this for possible other people handling the same problem.